# How to add each item into List in RxJava Android

Tags: java, android, lambda, retrofit, rx-java

My code is as below.

```
Observable<List<Appointment>> callAppointments = appointmentServiceRx.appointmentService.getConfirmedAppointments(user_id);
    callAppointments
            .flatMapIterable(appointments -> appointments)
            .flatMap(app -> Observable.zip(
                    app,
                    patientServiceRx.patientService.getPatientById(app.patient_id),
                    servicesRestRx.servicesAPIServiceRx.getSubserviceById(app.subservice_id),
                    (appointment, patient, subservice) -> this.createListItem(appointment, patient, subservice)
            ))
            .toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

With helper method as below

```
private Observable<AppointmentListItem> createListItem (Appointment app, Patient patient, Subservice subservice){
    AppointmentListItem item = new AppointmentListItem(app.appointment_id, subservice.subservice_name,
                                                        patient.patient_fullname, app.appointment_datetime);
    return Observable.just(item);
}
```

I got an error saying that the expected parameters and the actual arguments do not match when I tried to call createListItem in the Observable.zip

Here is the error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2EWH.png)

Please help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Timeline: Activity_idle` is a red herring and is irrelevant to your issue.

It seems that you use a bloody field for `appointment`! You only have a single instance of AppointmentListItem, that's why!

Edit: `Observable::zip` is your friend! Here's how I'd do it:

```
callAppointments
        .flatMapIterable(appointments -> appointments)
        .flatMap(app -> Observable.zip(
             app, 
             patientServiceRx.getService().getPatientById(app.patient_id),
             servicesRestRx.getService().getSubserviceById(app.subservice_id),
             (app, patient, subservice) -> this.createListItem(app, patient, subservice))
         .toList()
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(list -> {/*set adapter*/}, error -> {/* handle error */});
```

This has the added benefit of making the two per-appointment calls in parallel. Keep in mind that `flatMap` does not necessarily preserve the original ordering, so you may end up with AppointmentListItem in a different order than Appointments.

Comment: Ah I see. So how can I retrieve each result call into an object of Appointment rather than using field? Any suggestion?

Comment: I edited the original post. I also wonder why you use the `getService()` calls; why not inject the service directly?

Comment: could you please explain more about injecting the service directly? I am still a newbie in this kind of stuff.

Comment: Instead of doing the whole `servicesRestRx.getService().getSubserviceById(app.subservice_id)` dance, look into your DI system on how to use `servicesClient.getSubserviceById(app.subservice_id)` directly and skip the explicit `.setService()` stage - DI is supposed to help you there, and not become an extra hoop you need to jump through. This howewer is DI-dependent.

Comment: Ah got it. By the way I tried to use your solution but maybe somehow I got it wrong. I updated my code for your reference and please show me how to properly do it.

Comment: Sooo... how does it go wrong? Edit: ah, I read that - please make your utilityu method return the item directly and not the observable

Comment: The utility method createListItem? It still does not work, gives me error in the Observable.zip with the same error message.

Comment: Can you edit your post and append the bloody error message?

Comment: Look, that is not an error message, that is simply an artefact of failed type inference. See the "Expected Parameters" vs the "Actual Parameters", where the second column is all Object? This means that IDEA can't infer the types of the arguments. This can also be caused by other errors down the line, so make sure that this is the *only* error that you have.

Comment: It is the only error I get. By the way the getPatientById and getSubserviceById method is in Observable<> return type (from the retrofit interface). Does this affect my error?

Comment: Hmmmm... Give type parameters to the lambda. If that doesn't fix it, find out which version of Java you have, then try replacing the zip with a block where you have local variables for each parameter of the zip. Other than that, I have no idea, I'm heading to bed, it's 4 AM local time.

Comment: Ahahaha I got it now. The first argument in the Observable.zip should not be app. It should be Observable type of argument. So I replaced it with Observable.just(app) instead of just app. Thank you so much by the way for showing me how to use zip.